# configure bitvise ssh server for port forwarding (ssh tunnel)

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

I remember to setup an ssh tunnel, it requires to enable the "GatewayPorts" and "AllowTcpForwarding" of sshd_config file on the linux host where ssh server is installed.

I wonder do I need to do the same modifications if the ssh server is "bitvise ssh server" (on a windows machine)? If yes, where and how should I do it?

P.S.
i am having a windows 7 machine running Bitvise SSH server 7.39 (Standard use)

Comment: have you take a look here ? `https://www.bitvise.com/port-forwarding`

Comment: thanks. I have read that page, it does not mention anything about what I asked. I don't know whether or not it means there is no need to configure anything that I had to do on a linux machine.

Comment: The network diagrams of the link I gave you show how it works. Also, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712344/how-does-bitvise-port-forwarding-work. If this does not answer your question, be more specific in your request.